# How to loop directories in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

After CI build stage i have artifacts. list of apps can be more or less

```
/dist
  /apps
    /app1
    /app2
    /app3
```

and i want to get from dist/apps folder names

something like

```
script:
  - for (dir in ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/dist/apps)
    do
      ...
    done
```

how to access folder names in dist/apps by for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
script:
  -|
    cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/dist/apps
    folders=($(ls -d */))
    for folder in "${folders[@]}"
    do
      echo "${folder}"
    done
```

Comment: 1. unexpected '(' on `folders=($(ls -d */))`) 

2. syntax error: bad substitution on `for folder in "${folders[@]}"`