# How to loop directories in gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I found an answer here: [How to loop directories in gitlab-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73472888/how-to-loop-directories-in-gitlab-ci) but the answer results in a syntax error.

I have a structure like this:

- /src

  - /app1
  - /app2
  - /app3

I want to iterate through each of those apps and execute a script. How can I do this in gitlab-ci.yml/bash shell?

So far I can get a list of the folders but cannot figure out how to for loop them. This is what works:

```
      - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/src/
      - folders=($(ls -d */))
      - echo ${folders[@]}
```

This is what doesn't:

```
      - for folder in ${folders[@]}
        do
          echo "${folder}"
        done
```

The above for loop throws this error:
`syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, using shell *glob*:

```
  cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/src/
  folders=( */ )
  printf '%s\n' "${folders[@]}"
```

---

Globs are shell patterns that can be used for matching strings or expanding pathnames:
`[[ $name = Bob* ]]`
`rm -- *.txt`

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

---

**DO NOT USE `ls`** output for anything. `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing `ls` output with code are broken. Globs are much more simple AND correct: `for file in *.txt`. Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Added `DO NOT USE ls` part

Answer (score -2):

I was able to figure it out. The for loop was missing semi-colons:

```
for folder in ${folders[@]}; do
   echo "${folder}";
done
```

Comment: You way to parse `ls` is wrong, and you need to quote properly all variables, even `${folders[@]}` as `"${folders[@]}"`. Did you tried my answer?